# Fetching XML Data into SQL Server Select Statement

Tags: xml, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a DataSet and DataTable in Vb.net, I have converted that DataTable Value into XML so I can write all rows in one insert Statement in SQL Server rather calling the stored Procedure again and again for hundreds of thousands of rows.

Here I have sample XML and SQL script

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML = '<NewDataSet>
<Table>
  <ColVal>507.6100</ColVal>
</Table>
<Table>
  <ColVal>750.5800</ColVal>
</Table>
<Table>
  <ColVal>328.3600</ColVal>
</Table>
<Table>
  <ColVal>194.7700</ColVal>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>'

SELECT
a.b.value('Table[1]/ColVal[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits4
FROM @MyXML.nodes('NewDataSet') a(b)
```

1. **Result:** 507.6100

It returns only first row data, I want to fetch all rows.

Answer (score 1):

Move your query so the child level is at `Table` (Otherwise `Table[1]` will restrict the result to one):

```
SELECT
a.b.value('ColVal[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits4
FROM @MyXML.nodes('NewDataSet/Table') a(b)
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/16720)